# Is Baudrillard's work left-wing or right-wing?

Tags: political-philosophy, postmodernism, politics

What hints can we draw from his philosophy to situate his politics ? For example the French philosopher [Deleuze](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilles_Deleuze) is obviously an anticatapitalist as understood from his ideas in *[Anti-oedipus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-Oedipus)*.

Drawing from the common notions of the left-right political spectrum from the [political philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_philosophy), is [Baudrillard's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Baudrillard) work considered by philosophers to be left-wing or right-wing?

Comment: Considering his [taking inspiration from Marx](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/baudrillard/#EarlWritSystObjeMirrProd) and [publishing in New Left Review](https://newleftreview.org/issues/ii37/articles/jean-baudrillard-the-pyres-of-autumn) one need not be looking for clues very hard.

Comment: He is [post-modern](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/baudrillard/) and thus beyond the left/right divide.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Deleuze is also post-modern but calls himself a marxist even doe his work is very difficult to reconcile with marx other than being a critique of capitalism and and Conifold I saw!! thanks for the links Im confused then by his harsh critiques of marxism "fish in the water"

Comment: Added 'political-philosophy' tag. Clarified to overcome objections in votes for closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Baudrillard is probably best understood as broadly "leftist" I think it's worthwhile to recognize that philosophy does at least attempt to transcend the most basic political dichotomies. It's worth it, in other words, to try to understand the work for it's own sake and what it is saying, rather than pin it down to one or another of a pair of binarizing tendencies that reduce and oversimplify reality; while perhaps providing a satisfying simulation of theoretical activity, we have to recognize that simply asserting left-or-right doesn't tell us very much about the *philosophical* content, at best hinting at aspects of its expression and context and so forth.

Curiously enough, Deleuze's work was often perceived as something of a mystery for leftists of his generation; and at the very least we can say today with historical distance that Deleuze's work does not really culminate in a clear political theory but emits a relentlessly 'nonstandard' politics of disconformity and exponentiation -- emphasizing aberrant movements of depersonalization and deterritorialization, underscoring the importance of minor literatures, etc.